# How to make gradual blur in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Should get a gradient bluer like the design, but I can't do it, any ideas?

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH152.png)

This is how my code look

```
<ImageBackground 
    source={{uri: uri}} 
    style={styles.imageBackground} 
    imageStyle={styles.imageStyleBackground}
  >
      <BlurView
        style={{width: width * 0.78}}
        >
        <Text style={styles.date}>{date}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </BlurView>
  </ImageBackground>
```

I try to use BlurView component, but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to .

Answer (score 0):

Try with position: 'absolute'

```js
<>
  <Image
    source={{uri: uri}} 
    style={styles.imageStyleBackground}
  />
  <BlurView style={{width: width * 0.78, position: 'absolute'}}>
    <Text style={styles.date}>{date}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </BlurView>
</>
```

Comment: Blur works on specific text, but I don't understand how to make a gradient blur

Comment: There's other library for gradient called react-native-linear-gradient. I don't know how it will work with blurview. I think you should just use gradient with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an element on top of the image with `backdrop-filter:blur(5px)` that is masked with a gradient (eg. mask `linear-gradient(black, black, transparent)`)

[image]

See https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/jOBxGjr.

Comment: react native, pls

Comment: Looks like `mask` and `backdrop-filter` are not supported in react native. Perhaps you could use a svg filter overlay?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the react native tag.